# R correlation heatmap: showing only values in the threshold

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation

Here is the code (library: corrplot):

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="v1 v2 v3 v4 
1          1         5          3         2  
2          2         4          4         5  
3          3         3          5         1  
4          4         2          1         3  
5          5         1          2         4  
") 
cormat<-cor(df)
corrplot(cormat)
```

I would like to show in the heatmap ONLY the dots for the correlation coefficients between -0.2 and +0.2 (all others I would like to be just empty white squares).
Could somebody help please?

Answer (score 4):

Just set the unwanted values to zero:

```
tmp = cormat # Copy matrix
tmp[ tmp < -0.2 | tmp > 0.2 ] = 0
corrplot(tmp)
```

Comment: +1 (but I would probably not modify the original matrix, but a copy of it, in case the matrix is needed for some other calculations)